# How can I get the old Emojis or Kik-style Emojis on my updated GoSMS Pro?

Tags: sms, go-sms, emoticons

Okay, I use GoSMS Pro for my SMS, and I use SwiftKey for my keyboard. GoSMS just updated because of a "copyright issue" with their emojis, and now the only emojis available aren't really ideal for me.

I am fairly new to Android and I have no idea how all of these installable "Emoji plugins" interface with my keyboard and/or GoSMS or other third-party SMS apps.

**Here are my main questions:**

1. Does anyone know of an Emoji pack that mimics the default Emoji style of Kik?
2. Do I *have* to use Emojis from GoSMS/by their developer as a plugin?
3. Will my downloaded Emoji plugins interface with SwiftKey and show to others I send SMS to the same as they look to me?

**TL;DR Ultimately I just want to pick a set of Emojis and have it work with SwiftKey and GoSMS. If anyone can help I would really appreciate it! :)**

Comment: Really you should ask this question to SwiftKey and/or GoSMS

Comment: I just figured that this is something that most Android users seem to have the hang of, yet I don't really fully understand yet. It's not just GoSMS updating their app, it's more of a generalized set of questions for Android users who are familiar with custom Emojis and things like that.

Comment: Also posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/2sb65f/how_can_i_get_the_old_emojis_or_kikstyle_emojis/).

Answer (score 0):

I get Textra for better view of emoji and for keyboard i use Decoration Keyboard ... but there you haven't all of the emoji that's the ugly part

but is better than nothing

Answer (score -1):

To solve all of this, I just use [Emoji Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crazystudio.emoji.kitkat).

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. How did it solve the issues? What is it, where to find it?